# jQuery: Get value from input array with predefined array key

Tags: html, jquery

I have an html input array with predefined array key (the predefined key is needed for further action) like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tests[5]" value="b">
<input type="hidden" name="tests[8]" value="a">
```

i tried to get the value using a jQuery method like this:

```
var testsValues = $('input[name="tests[]"]').map(function () {
                return this.value; // $(this).val()
           }).get();

console.log(testsValues);
```

it always gives an empty result, but if i remove the predefined key it will not give an empty result

```
<input type="hidden" name="tests[]" value="b">
<input type="hidden" name="tests[]" value="a">
```

what is the right way to retrieve the input array values with the predefined key?

Comment: Try `input[name^=tests]`.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Comment: @RatajS thanks i can retrieve the value, but how can i also retrieve the predefined array key?

Comment: I edited my code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use better selector like $('input[name^="tests"]') to get elements names starting by **tests** and then loop them with each.

EDIT : to get the key, you can use split the name with separator "**[**" of the input to get second element **[1]** and then replace last element to make it clean "**]**".

https://api.jquery.com/each/

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```js
$('input[name^="tests"]').each(function() {
  let inputName = $(this).attr("name");
  let inputKey = inputName.split('[')[1].replace(']', '');
  let inputVal = $(this).val();
  console.log("Name : " + inputName + " - Key : " + inputKey + " - " + " Value : " + inputVal);
  
  if (inputKey == 5) {
    // do something
    console.log("Key is egal to 5 - Value : " + inputVal);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="tests[5]" value="b">
<input type="hidden" name="tests[8]" value="a">
```